# unlinking warning in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

I want to delete a image from a directory using codeigniter..

I have tried many but each time it throws warning... that Message:

> unlink(): http does not allow unlinking

I have tried following.

Please say which is true among this or all are wrong?

```
****/* $f = $this->input->post("imgs");                //this is the file name come from view
                $directory1 = "assets/images/";
                $paths = base_url().$directory1.$f;
                $dest = base_url().$directory1."imgx/".$f;
                $rnm =$paths."_deleted_".$this->input->post('ida');


                opendir(base_url().directory1);

                //echo $paths;
                /*if(file_exists($paths))
                    echo "exists";
                else
                    echo "<img src='".$paths."'>";  echo "not exists";          //shows not exists but load the image           

                if(unlink($paths)) {
                echo 'deleted successfully';
                }
                else {
                echo 'errors occured';          //shows eror occured
                }
                //exit;
                //unlink($paths);
                /*@chmod(base_url().'assets/images/'.$f, 0750);
                @unlink(base_url().'assets/images/'.$f);*/
                //rename($paths,$rnm);*/
```

How to get rid from this..plz help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using url, use the physical path in the server to delete a file.

Replace the following with the physical path

```
$paths = base_url().$directory1.$f;
```

Comment: instead of base_url(), have you tried the folder path?

Comment: is there any configuration required for unlinking

Comment: Does the user has permission to delete?

Comment: i dont know.. how to get oermission

Comment: and i tried physical path.. it load image by that path.. but say not exist

Comment: Check the folder permission and make sure that there is permission to delete.

Comment: how to check ?? can u please say

Comment: How you are accessing the server ? using filezilla?

Comment: Then why can't you go to the physical path and right click the folder and check the permissions tab?

Comment: The folder to which you are trying to upload.

Comment: i want to delete.. and i am working locally on laptop.. so permission i think is given..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.. This worked for me. Do not use base_url() while defining the path. Instead define path to the specific file this way:

```
$paths ='./assets/images/'.$f;
$dest  ='./assets/images/'.$f;
```